# Where should I post a question about logic circuit minimisation?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a question about some logic circuits (I have the Boolean functions and truth tables) that I would like to minimise. Where would I post a question about this? I was thinking Physics firstly but possibly somewhere else?

Comment: [electronics.se] would be a better fit I believe.

Comment: If you post it in Physics, it is likely to get closed as being about engineering, not physics.

Comment: [Boolean algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boolean-algebra) is on-topic in the Math stack. Of course, no matter where you post this you need to show your own work on the problem, eg show a naive implementation and your best minimization so far.

Comment: @Blue That looks like it should have been an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions about logic circuits are generally off topic here. You could try [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com) and see if it would be on topic there.